# QT Webkit seems oblivious to new wireless network connection

Tags: qt, embedded-linux

I am building a app that has a javascript layer on top that uses QtWebkit to occasionally access web pages; however if I start my app up without a wireless connection and then set up a connection (using ifup then a device connect then dhcpcd to get the gateway set up) the Javascript continues to be oblivious to the gateway to the wider world.

QNetworkConfigurationManager in my QtApp reports the connection is up OK after I updateConfigurations() and the IP and netmask are reported OK as well.

wget from the command prompt happily obtains whatever webpage I ask it to get.

But if I create an instance of QNetworkAccessManager then
manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://www.google.com/index.html"))); replies that it cannot reach the page.

Do I need to poke an update the QtWebKit somehow for the JS layer to update it's configuration as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been found; the implementation of Qt for embedded we have has an error in it for our implementation of uclibc. This has been patched by the (deleted for security reasons) company that supplied us with the libraries for our embedded solution.